# Jquery chained selects any clues what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, data-binding

I am using the data attr to select, I want to filter based on the data attribute of the first select.
Here is my code, please let me know what ? Excuse the messiness of my code, I'm a  javascript/Jquery noob

The html block/////////

```
<select id="selectOne">
                    <option data-team='{"team":"Engineering"}'>Engineering </option>
                    <option   data-team='{"team": "Software"}'>Software Development</option>
                    <option data-team='{"team": "HumanResources"}'>Human Resources</option>
                    <option  data-team='{"team": "MarkettingAndSales"}'>Marketting and Sales</option>
                    <option  data-team='{"team": "Administrative"}'>Administrative</option>
                    <option  data-team='{"team": "Others"}' class="others">Others</option>
                </select>

                <select id="selectTwo">
                    <option  class="two" data-Speciality='{"team": "Software", "Speciality": "WebDevelopment"}'>Web Development </option>
                    <option  class="two" data-Speciality='{"team": "Engineering", "Speciality": "WebApplication"}'>Application Development </option>
                    <option  class="two" data-Speciality='{"team": "Software", "Speciality": "WebDevelopment"}'>UI/UX Design</option>
                    <option  class="two" data-Speciality='{"team": "Others", "Speciality": "ScientificResearch"}'>Scientific / Research</option>
                    <option  class="two" data-Speciality='{"team": "Engineering", "Speciality": "ScientificResearch"}'>Computer Hardware / Networking</option>
                    <option class="two" data-Speciality='{"team": "Others", "Speciality": "Others"}'>Others</option>
                </select>

$(function(){
    // function to use ajax calls to filter the table data depending on the select forms value
            $("#selectOne").change(function() {
                $("#selectTwo").hide();
                var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
                $('#selectTwo option [data-team===selected]').show();



            console.log( $(selected).data('team') );

            //the filtering mechanism based on the class
         });
```

/// apparently I'm not getting the value of the second select
any clue why?

```
$(function(){
    // function to use ajax calls to filter the table data depending on the select forms value
        $("#selectOne").change(function() {
    var selected=$(this).find('option:selected').data('team').teamName;
    console.log(selected);
    var selectTwo= $('#selectTwo').val().data('Speciality').team;
     console.log(selectTwo);

})
```

Comment: Post your HTML or make http://jsfiddle.net/ of it.

Comment: @AleksandrM, my html is posted, its the select portion, I wnat to understand why that didnt work, already used classes to filter it out, but thought the data api should be able to do a similar thing

Answer (score 1):

You can't show/hide `option`s like that, at least not in every browser.

You have to actively manipulate the DOM, i.e. removing and adding elements based on your filter logic, and you'll end up with a big mess with just plain jQuery.

If you need such feature, I'd go with anything that decouples data from UI client-side : [here you can find](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) a lot of solutions.

Comment: Thanks, decided to go with a plugin instead

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want that instead:

```
var selected = $(this).val();    
$('#selectTwo').val(selected).show();
```

Not sure about what you are expecting.

Comment: I tried that, it doesnt work, Thanks for the suggestion, though. I'll look at @moonwave99's suggestion.

Comment: I want the values of the selected option to change, I have edited the question with the html block I am trying to manipulate.